# Is it faster to access a struct or a subset of bit in a byte?

Tags: c++, c, performance

Let's say I have three parts of information and they can be stored using as a portion of a byte.

- info_a is 3 bit long
- info_b is 2 bit long
- info_c is 3 bit long

I don't have any memory constraints.

The first implementation is

```
struct info{
  unsigned char info_a;
  unsigned char info_b;
  unsigned char info_c;
}
```

the second implementation is

```
unsigned char info; // bit 0..2 info_a, bit 3..4 info b, bit 5..7 info_c
```

So which one is the faster version for

- storing data
- retrieving data

?

Comment: There is no definitive answer for this. If you have a specific platform in mind, write tests for both options and benchmark.

Comment: You could write a simple test program to test this.  My gut says non word size access will be slower than word size access.

Comment: This depends on a lot of things in the specific CPU instruction set. Can it set individual bits, does it work faster on types that is of the given alignment requirement (32 bits for example) and so on. It isn't meaningful to discuss this without a specific system in mind.

Comment: If caching is relevant, having the data compact might be an advantage.

Comment: You said storing and retrieving data. Do you mean writing a bunch of these records to disk? Or do you mean accessing the sub-values in memory as part of some code loop?

Comment: I was about to post an answer with c++11 bit fields.  Let the compiler handle implementation details, because it knows what system it's currently on. Programmers generally don't do optimization unless you can measure a problem to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one instance of these then I don't think there'll be any meaningful difference as they are both smaller than a word in length.  The single char version will possibly slower as you'll have to do some bit manipulation that you don't need to with the struct.

If you have a million of these in an array and loop then I'd expect the more compact data of the single char will lessen the number of cache misses, which will make up for any tiny loss in the bit manipulation to get at the data.

But as ever, you'll have to test it in your particular environment to find out for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The struct way will be faster on most typical modern platforms.  This is because a single instruction can be used to load or store a single byte, whereas sub-byte loads and stores require extra operations.

Of course, if you have many times when you need to set all three values at once, or clear them all at once, or you are memory-constrained (e.g. you store billions of these values), the sub-byte solution will have an advantage.

Comment: It completely depends on the architecture and the surrounding code. E.g. on ARM the bitfields can be much faster using bitfield instructions and keeping all data in a single register (single/no memory access).